# Adafruit Ultimate GPS connection not working

Tags: gps

New to PI!!  From a new fresh load of OS:
I followed the instructions to connect the GPS HAT to a Pi and run the basic test from:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi/basic-test

Then tried to set up gpsd from:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi/use-gpsd

All worked until I tried `gpsmon`.  I get :

```
tcp://localhost:2947
(84) .... version..
(32) .. device...
(122) ... class...
```

Then the system hangs with no response

If I run `cgps -s` the formated page appears with 0 for results.
The light on the  Hat is blinking once a min so I know I have a connection.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. It is entirely possible that someone here will have or be familiar with the GPS HAT you've bought from AdaFruit. However, you should also try AdaFruit. They typically have reasonable documentation with their products, and last I checked provided some email or chat support. Please note I'm not suggesting you've come to the wrong place, I'm just saying take advantage of all options :) There are several documents listed at the bottom of AdaFruit's webpage you linked... have you reviewed any of those?

Comment: @GuyB were you able to get the correct response when you used `stty -F /dev/serial0 raw 9600 cs8 clocal -cstopb` in the basic test?

Comment: I am posting a link for anyone that is trying to get the adafruit ultimate GPS hat to work:  Follow this to the letter and it will get you going: Thanks Steve  http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/raspberry-pi3-gps-time.html